# How can I plot the intersection of two functions of three variables?

Tags: matlab

I've got two equations:

```
eqn1 = (wx^2)/4 + (wy^2)/10 + (wz^2)/15 == 1;
eqn2 = (wx^2)/3 + (wy^2)/7  + (wz^2)/5 == 1;
```

How can I find the 3d ellipse that results from their intersection? I've tried picking arbitrary values for one variable and then solving the system of equations for the other 2 but had no luck. Thanks for any help.

Comment: did I answer your question correctly? If yes, you may consider accepting it by clicking the checkmark on the left-hand side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need `ezsurf` or `ezmesh`

As you can see, if you multiply `eqn2` by `1/3`, and do `eqn1-eqn2`, then you get the following equation:

```
eqn3 : 0.1389*(wx^2)+0.0524*(wy^2)-(2/3)=0
```

You can use `ezsurf` to plot it:

```
ezsurf('0.1389*(wx^2)+0.0524*(wy^2)-(2/3)');
```

You get a figure like this:

[image: Intersection of two given ellipses]